# One consumer multiple topics causes potential thread issue?

Tags: java, multithreading, hadoop, apache-kafka

I have a REST service, lets call it MDD, which has one kafka consumer. When I FIRST start the rest service, another service tells MDD's consumer to subscribe to a specific topic, everything seems to go fine.

Then the service tells MDD's consumer to subscribe to another topic. The way I am doing it right now is via consumer.assign() method. Basically, if a new topic is introduced to which the consumer is not assigned to, I assign this new topic to the consumer. So the one consumer is now assigned to 2 different topics.

This consumer polls the messages and deposits them into HDFS.

Now what I have noticed, is when the subscription for the 2nd topic comes in, sometimes I get the error about failing to append to file in HDFS and when I looked at the logs, it was trying to append some data that should not have been appended till later on.
For example, data to kafka comes in this order A, B, C. When MDD is done appending A to HDFS, it tries to append C (rather than B) and simultaneously tries to append B as well. Also another note, no data is coming from the first topic at this point, only data from second topic is streaming in. So currently, only one kafka topic has data streaming in at any given time.

Anyone have any idea what could be going on? Is there potential of some thread issues being created when I assign ONE consumer to multiple topics? Because everything seems to go fine when the consumer is assigned to ONE topic but as soon as its assigned to more than ONE topic, I get failed to append to file in HDFS because some other writer already owns the lease. This error does not happen frequently, just very randomly.

Also would a recommended fix be every time a new topic is created, create a new kafka consumer?

Answer (score 0):

It's definitely valid and doable to have only one consumer read messages from multiple topics. The problem you ran into is because of the fact that Kafka does not currently support both using manual partition assignment(with KafkaConsumer#assign) and group management(with KafkaConsumer#subscribe).

To support subscribing newly-created topics, you could try to invoke KafkaConsumer#subscribe to which a regular expression is passed, matching all the newly-created topics.

Comment: can you elaborate more on this please: The problem you ran into is because of the fact that Kafka does not currently support both using manual partition assignment(with KafkaConsumer#assign) and group management(with KafkaConsumer#subscribe). I am still not understanding why the problem is caused.

Comment: Simply put, you should not use KafkaConsumer.subscribe and KafkaConsumer.assign both, so stick to use only one of them.

Comment: I am only using one. First I was using assign, then I tried switching to subscribe and am still getting the same error